# List instances in subnetwork

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hi I am trying list compute instances in a specific network, and subnetwork, and can't seem to get the filtering right. For example, I have a network named "prod-net" with a subnetwork named "app-central". When I run the search I just get "Listed 0 items".

```
~  gcloud compute instances list --filter='network:prod-net'
Listed 0 items.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems it cannot be filtered by network, because when you don't apply the filter there's no NETWORK column. For example, you can use --filter=ZONE~us to filter instances in US zones.

Comment: as @Dagang mentioned, --filter flag takes into consideration the listed columns. However, I would suggest filing a feature request in this public issue tracker [1] in order to have this feature available in future releases. [1]: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list

Answer (score 4):

The `--filter` flag doesn't operate on the table data, but rather the underlying rich resource object. To see this object, run `gcloud compute instances list --format=json`.

What you're looking for in this case is:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list --filter='networkInterfaces.network=prod-net'
```

(I switched the `:` to `=` because the former means "contains" and the latter means an exact match. See `gcloud topic filters` for more).

Comment: I needed to do `gcloud compute instances list --filter='networkInterfaces[0].network=prod-net'` to make it work.

Comment: Interesting, I just verified that my original answer still works. Are you on the latest version of gcloud (138.0.0)?

Comment: Ah, you are right. On my Ubuntu VM, `apt` tells me that "google-cloud-sdk is already the newest version (111.0.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.0)". When using the Google Cloud Shell on the GCE web console, I am on version 138 and your command works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed filter GCE instances by subnetwork using `gcloud`.

You need to filter by `networkInterfaces.subnetwork` and the literal value to compare with, is the full subnet resource url, not just the subnet-name.

The "resource url" for your subnet can be obtained by:

`gcloud compute networks subnets list <YOUR_SUBNET_NAME> --format=flattened`

Example:

```
$ gcloud compute networks subnets list sg-zk-1 --project my-gcp-project --format=flattened
---
creationTimestamp:     2017-04-20T02:22:17.853-07:00
gatewayAddress:        10.9.19.33
id:                    6783412628763296550
ipCidrRange:           10.9.19.32/28
kind:                  compute#subnetwork
name:                  sg-zk-1
network:               valkyrie
privateIpGoogleAccess: True
region:                asia-southeast1
selfLink:              https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-gcp-project/regions/asia-southeast1/subnetworks/sg-zk-1
```

In the above example, the subnet-name is `sg-zk-1`.

The corresponding resource URL for the subnet is the value of the `selfLink` which is `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-gcp-project/regions/asia-southeast1/subnetworks/sg-zk-1`.

Now that I have the `subnet_url` I can filter the instances belonging to it:

```
$ subnet_url="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-gcp-project/regions/asia-southeast1/subnetworks/sg-zk-1"

$ gcloud compute instances list --filter="networkInterfaces.subnetwork=${subnet_url}"
NAME            ZONE               MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP  STATUS
sg-zookeeper-4  asia-southeast1-b  n1-standard-2               10.9.19.37                RUNNING
sg-zookeeper-5  asia-southeast1-b  n1-standard-2               10.9.19.38                RUNNING
sg-zookeeper-1  asia-southeast1-a  n1-standard-2               10.9.19.34                RUNNING
sg-zookeeper-2  asia-southeast1-a  n1-standard-2               10.9.19.35                RUNNING
sg-zookeeper-3  asia-southeast1-a  n1-standard-2               10.9.19.36                RUNNING
```